# Is it possible to disable people pinging @everyone and @here using "say" command on discord bot?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I've tried a few methods to stop people from pinging everyone but what i want is something where if the message has "@everyone" or "@here" i can make the bot reply a few different ways

here is my current code

```
const Discord = require ('discord.js');

const { FILE } = require('dns');

const client = new Discord.Client();

const prefix = ".";

const fs = require('fs');

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('IM ONLINE GUYS!!!');
});

client.on('message', message =>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/)
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command === 'ping'){
        client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);
    } else if (command == 'pong'){
        client.commands.get('pong').execute(message, args);
    } else if (command == 'help'){
        client.commands.get('help').execute(message, args, Discord);
    } else if (command == 'kill'){
        client.commands.get('kill').execute(message, args);
    } else if (command == 'quote'){
        client.commands.get('quote').execute(message, args);
    } else if (command == 'kiss'){
        client.commands.get('kiss').execute(message, args);
    } else if (command == 'hug'){
        client.commands.get('hug').execute(message, args);
    } else if (command == 'pet'){
        client.commands.get('pet').execute(message, args);   
    } else if (command === 'say'){
   const sayMessage = message.content.split(' ').slice(1).join(' ');

   message.channel.send(sayMessage);
} else if (command === 'music-h'){
    client.commands.get('music-h').execute(message, args, Discord)
}
})

client.login('token')
```

and i am refering to the

```
} else if (command === 'say'){
   const sayMessage = message.content.split(' ').slice(1).join(' ');

   message.channel.send(sayMessage);
```

part

Im going to explain it better here: I am trying to make the bot respond with something else when someone pings @everyone or @here in their ".say" message

example:

".say @everyone"

"Nice try bub, its not gonna work with me"

and maybe a couple other responses along with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes of course!

```js
if (message.content.includes('@everyone') || message.content.includes('@here')) {
message.channel.send('Nice try bub, its not gonna work with me')
```

Let me know if you need further help, cheers!

Comment: thank you! I had an issue with it sending both "Nice try bub, its not gonna work with me" and "@everyone" but i fixed it myself.